# How do I change the versions of certain files in subversion and form a new commit?

Tags: svn

E.g., I have the following files under version control: file1, file2, file3, all at version 10. Now I want to switch file1 to a different version, say 5 and file3 to say, version 8. I want version 11 to contain these files (file1 (as in v5), file2 (as in v10) and file3 (as in v8)) , so that anytime I checkout from the repo henceforth, or someone else does, they get these files (instead of all at v10). However, when I try to commit, it doesn't commit! The only way I can force it to commit is to make a subtle change (like adding a harmless space) to a file and then committing. Is there some way to do it or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Revert the changes and then commit everything, for example:

```
svn merge -r10:5 file1
svn merge -r10:8 file3

svn commit -m "Reverted file1 to revision 5 and file3 to revision 8"
```

By calling merge with the revisions going backwards, it will revert any changes made in those revisions on the file you are issuing the command for.